# PHP+ODBC - Get return value from stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, odbc

I need to use some old procedures, which return a status code. *Rewriting procedures or rewriting PHP to use native driver is not possible for now.*

Is it possible to get the return value?  If so, how ?

The underlying database is MS SQL 2008.  I'm calling the stored procedure using this:

```
$res = odbc_execute( "EXEC procedure_name @param = 'value', ..." );
```

Comment: What underlying database is being used, please?  And how are you calling the stored procedure?  And which PHP-level ODBC interface are you using?

Comment: And which PHP-level ODBC interface are you using? - ? sorry, i don't understand this

Comment: There are multiple ways to work with ODBC from PHP.  Your code addition tells me that you're using [the older ODBC functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) instead of PDO.  I'm going to edit the tags on this post to hopefully get more useful attention.

Answer (score 0):

A very old question, but I have just had to solve it by trial and error. If the stored procedure is programmed to return a value, then it can be obtained via the usual odbc call:

```
$results = odbc_fetch_row ($res);
```

Then determine the structure of the returned array via:

```
var_dump ($results);
```